# Makefile error when using conditional compilation

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

what is wrong with this `makefile`. I keep getting the following error. platform is being set in upper level makefile and is being passed to the sub makefile. I do use the same syntax for "ifneq" elsewhere in the makefiles. but this one is causing termination of compilation. not sure what's wrong Any white space issue that the GNU make is unable to understand? Please help.

```
error:
---------------
| ifneq (,ulp_l100-3_8)
| /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `,ulp_l100-3_8'
| /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifneq (,ulp_l100-3_8)'
---------------

***********
all:

    $(MAKE) -C $(PWD)/$(BCM_SDK)

    ifneq (,$(platform))
            $(MAKE) -C $(PWD)/$(BCM_SDK)/$(BCM_SDK_LINUX_USER)/$(platform)
    fi

*********
```

I want to call the 2nd MAKE in above code only when the platform variable is set. it is set like this.

```
export platform = "ulp_l100-3_8"
```

If it is not set then do not call the make. I tried using `$(platform)` on either side of comparison, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: In the 'ifneq( first_statment, second_stmnt)', first_statment is the 'PATH' while second one is value. Please check that, it may be the error.

Comment: If I remember correctly, directives like e.g. `ifneq` must start in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help. 
I goofed up on 2 things.
1. ifneq was not on the first line
2. I mixed up shell scripting and makefile. ifneq needs to be terminated with endif not fi like in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all:

    $(MAKE) -C $(PWD)/$(BCM_SDK)

ifdef platform
    $(MAKE) -C $(PWD)/$(BCM_SDK)/$(BCM_SDK_LINUX_USER)/$(platform)
fi
```